# C++ Static linking weird behavior

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a big project, and it happened that in two places there are functions which take the same arguments and have the same name, although they do a different thing. I was adviced to use facade approach and place everything in static libraries. However it made program extremely strange. Functions are not separated from each other, despite the fact that wrappers are separate static libs and have separate name spaces. Always function from A.lib is called- also by B::BF() wrapper.

executable:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include "A/AWrapper.h"
#include "B/BWrapper.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"A="<<A::AF(2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"B="<<B::BF(2)<<std::endl;   //uses function int F(int x) from A lib

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

File structure is as follows:

Dir A:

```
FA.h, FA.c  //function int F(int x) is defined - C language
AWrapper.h, AWrapper.cpp //a simple wrapper function AF of int F(int x); C++
```

Dir B:

```
FB.h, FB.c  //function int F(int x) is defined - C language
BWrapper.h, BWrapper.cpp //a simple wrapper function AF of int F(int x); C++
```

And above was the simple program calling those. Detailed files listing:

A library--------------:

FA.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED

int F(int x);

#endif // A_H_INCLUDED
```

FA.c:

```
#include "FA.h"

int F(int x)
{
   return x*x;
}
```

AWrapper.h:

```
#ifndef AWRAPPER_H_INCLUDED
#define AWRAPPER_H_INCLUDED

namespace A{
   int AF(int x);
}

#endif // AWRAPPER_H_INCLUDED
```

AWrapper.cpp

```
#include "AWrapper.h"

extern "C"{
#include "FA.h"
}

namespace A{   
    int AF(int x)
    {
       return F(x);
    }
}
```

B library--------------:
FB.h:

```
#ifndef B_H_INCLUDED
#define B_H_INCLUDED

int F(int x);

#endif // B_H_INCLUDED
```

FB.c:

```
#include "FB.h"

#define n 5

int F(int x)
{
   return -x*x*n;
}
```

BWrapper.h:

```
#ifndef BWRAPPER_H_INCLUDED
#define BWRAPPER_H_INCLUDED

namespace B{

   int BF(int x);
}

#endif // BWRAPPER_H_INCLUDED
```

BWrapper.h:

```
#include "BWrapper.h"

extern "C"{
#include "FB.h"
}

namespace B{

   int BF(int x)
   {
      return F(x);
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the compiled 'B' static library? Make sure it's calling the right function? Though it's possible that the linker is replacing it when it links in the 'A' static library.

Comment: Well... it works fine when there is no A lib linked.

Comment: You cannot have two global functions having the same name in a single statically-linked binary. No amount of wrapping will help. Rename one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't solve it that way. If you have a "free function" that is not in a namespace or a class [and not inlined], it will have the same name (in C++ if it has the same arguments/return type) - so no matter how much wrapping you do later, the linker will still link against the first version of the function it finds.

There are two obvious solutions:

1. Rename (one of) the function(s) so that they no longer have the same name.
2. Wrap the very basic function(s) into a namespace and/or class, so that it gets a qualified name.

Either of these solutions involve modifying the FA.c and/or FB.c.

An alternative would be to use a shared library for each group of functions - such that FA.c and FB.c are never in the same shared library, and statically link FA.o to one shared library, and FB.o to another shared library. But this will mean having shared libraries, and I expect you choose not to do that in the first place when choosing static linking.

If the code is compileable (that is, it doesn't use `new`, `delete`, `this` or other C++ keywords as variable names, and doesn't go too wild in passing pointers from one type to another without casts, etc) in C++, you can also do something like this:

FA.cpp:

```
namespace A
{
    #include "FA.c"
}
```

FB.cpp:

```
namespace B
{
    #include "FB.c"
}
```

Comment: If that was a C++ code there would be no problem, but C does not support namespaces. How can I workaround it? Any trick? And renaming a function that is in about thousand of other files seems rather creepy :]

Comment: @Misery: Using a smart IDE, this kind of refactoring should be relatively easy. Also, you probably have loads of unit tests that show that your refactoring went well ;)

Comment: See my edit, you could move the function into a C++ environment with a simple include. But there are restrictions on this, as some C code doesn't compile well in a C++ compiler. Otherwise, arne's solution is your best option. Or some nasty macros... ;)

Comment: @arne: I am using VS 2010 on Win and Code::Blocks on Linux, do you know how to force those IDEs to work as I need?

Comment: Pity, the real function uses a lots of C - specific headers and stuff - I wouldn't risk moving it there.

Comment: Why not try? It MAY work, you know... A lot of C headers are fine for compiling in C++. Note that this is one of those things that are OBVIOUS whether it works or not - you will know if it compiled, and if it compiled, it's 99.9% certain it will also WORK.

Comment: C still has a card or two up the sleeve. `#define F F_renamed_to_FA` in FA.h, recompile the world, and your project is as good as new.

Comment: @Misery: I don't know VS or Code::Blocks, but in Eclipse it's rather simple, so I assume it's also possible in your IDEs since it's such a basic operation.